# Get data from 2 tables based on a junction table

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, join

I have the following 3 tables:

```
1. offers                     2. producers                3. products

ProducerID | ProductID        ProducerID | ProducerName   ProductID | ProductName
-----------|----------        -----------|-------------   ----------|------------
1          |    1                  1     | John                1    | Wood
1          |    2                  2     | Bill                     | Metal
2          |    1
```

What I am trying to do is get the information using join statements. Here's what I've got so far:

```
SELECT producers.ProducerName, products.ProductName
FROM offers
(RIGHT JOIN producers
ON offers.ProducerID = producers.ProducerID
RIGHT JOIN products
ON offers.ProductID = products.ProductID)
WHERE ProductName=${ProductName}
```

What I'm struggling with is the WHERE statement. I want the user to input the `ProductName` they're searching for, that to get converted to the `ProductID`, and then get compared in the `WHERE` clause. How should that part look like?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  You also appear to be calling the SQL from an application, so you should include a tag for that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need outer joins.  So just use:

```
select pr.ProducerName, p.ProductName
from offers o join
     producers pr
     on o.ProducerID = p.ProducerID join
     products p
     on o.ProductID = p.ProductID
where p.ProductName = ?
```

Note the use of `?`.  This is a *parameter placeholder*.  If you are calling the query from an application, you should be passing in the value as a parameter, not munging the query string.

Also note the use of table aliases which make the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using simple joins:

```
select pe.producerName, pu.productName
from producers pe
inner join offers o on o.producerID = pe.producerID
inner join products pu on pu.productID = o.productID
where pu.producerName = ?
```

`right join`s do not seem needed here. Also, there is no need to nest the joins within parentheses (this just makes the query less readable, for no benefit). Finally, table aliases (here, `pe`, `o` and `pu`) make the query shorter and easier to write and read.